# Check if stored procedure exists accordingly create or alter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to check if a stored procedure already defined in db. If defined I have to execute alter script else create.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'EmployeeInternalReferenceNumber_Copy')
    BEGIN
        DROP  Procedure [dbo].[EmployeeInternalReferenceNumber_Copy]
    END
 Go
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmployeeInternal]
```

Above script is not working as I do not want to drop proc just alter or create. I am using SP2

Comment: *I'm using SP2* - SP2 of what!?!?!? SQL Server versions are labeled with year numbers - 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 or 2019 - so which version (and the SP2 of that) are you using??

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server version 2016+, you can simply use:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmployeeInternal] 
AS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop procedure if exists` instead of `if exists`

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS EmployeeInternalReferenceNumber_Copy;
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmployeeInternal]
```

Or if you want to alter procedure `EmployeeInternal` then use `alter` instead of `create`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmployeeInternal]
```